# Gnuplot fine grained ranges(grid)

Tags: gnuplot

I have this graph created with gnuplot[image]

However the red line at the bottom seems like very straight due to the y-axis range although it is not (it should look like the blue one). How can make the range of the y-axis very fine grained (lots of ticks) so very small values of the red graph can be visible ? Hope I was clear thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions to your question.

1. Use a logarithmic scale with `set logscale y`. This would change the look of your plot quite a bit but you would still have all the data related to a single scale and it would most probably introduce a "higher resolution" to your red line.
2. Introduce a second y-axis like in [this](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot1-e.html#5.2) example.

As far as I know, it is not possible to increase the resolution only on a specific part of an axis. I think, this would lead to more confusion than it would do any good.